# Ghost blog RSS feed broken: Input is not proper UTF-8

Tags: node.js, utf-8, rss, ghost-blog

When accessing /rss I see an error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 6 at column 575: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>
> Bytes: 0x08 0x75 0x74 0x20

I checked the settings in `index.js` and they seem to be right. Is this a template issue or something that is related to Ghost's core?

Thanks

**Issue resolved!** There was some invisible character that was hidden in one of the blog posts that destroyed the feed. Go find it!

Comment: Care enough to give a link? Since when do you have the issue? Did you mess with ghost's files?

Comment: I added the link to the origin al question. I didn't mess with the files, but I changed a lot in the theme. Is RSS theme or core related?